# Ingress Controller annotations for GCP cloud

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-ingress

What are the equivalent of the following annotations for GCP ingress? I'm trying to use a custom nginx-template but I can't find the reference for the following annotations. In the [github answer](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/636) they're using AWS but I need to achieve this using GCP.

```
"service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol": "*"
"service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol": "tcp"
"service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports": "https"
"service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout": "60"
```

I'm using ingress class `nginx`

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
```

And I'm trying to do Ingress TCP SSL termination in GCP Kubernetes cluster using Ingress controller.

I want the traffic from `https://example.com:1234` to be redirect to `http://example.com:1234`. The backend port 1234 is HTTP only.

Here's a example for AWS - https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.1/guide/service/annotations/

I need something like that for GCP

Comment: Your question is unclear, and also not related to programming and thus belongs on https://ServerFault.com You say GCP but do you mean GKE? and if not GKE, then are you running your own k8s with its own `cloud-provider` set to GCP? Are you looking for more annotations like `cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type:`?

Comment: Yea its for GKE. For AWS services Kubernetes have a page with all the annotations listed out. But I can't find a annotation list for GCP services. Just like AWS, for Nginx controller, nginx has a list of supported annotations listed in their docs.

Comment: Here's a example for AWS - https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.1/guide/service/annotations/

I need something like that for GCP

Comment: There are some annotations for gce ingress: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/load-balance-ingress

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will find something like a list of all `GCP Ingress` annotations. The only ones close to it can be found on [Github](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/tree/master/pkg/annotations).

If you think that list of all `GCP annotations` would be useful, you can [file a Feature Request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) at `Google Public Issue Tracker` and ask for changes to the documentation with all the annotations supported by [GKE Ingress](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce).

In some cases you can use `GCP LB` (like HTTP(S) Load Balancer) + [NEG](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs) + `GKE`, but accordingly to the doc [Choosing a load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/choosing-load-balancer), only External Network TCP/UDP support any `LoadBalancer` destination ports and accordingly to the doc [Zonal network endpoint groups overview](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/zonal-neg-concepts) it's not possible to use External TCP/UDP Network Load Balancers with `NEGs`.

However, in your question, you mention that you are using the annotation `kubernetes.io/ingress.class:" nginx "`, which means you are using [Nginx Ingress](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) (If `ingress.class` is not specified, it's using default which is `kubernetes.io/ingress.class:"gce"`).

`Nginx Ingress` has a list of all [annotations](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/), but I think the most interesting for you would be [TCP and UDP Service Disclosure](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/).